# Printing an object after putting it into a map

Tags: c++, dictionary

```
class Task
{


public:
    string study;
    int time;
    bool made;
    int priority;
}
class Day 
{
    public:
        string date = "undefined";
        int aims = 0;
        vector <Task> tasks;
}
```

i have 2 classes,where i use vector to keep data from both.
this project is a daily planner for one day.
Now i need to improve it to store more days,tutor wants me to use MAP.

```
map<string, Day>Days;
map<string, Day>::iterator it;
            Days.insert(pair<string, Day>(s, d));
            for (it = Days.begin(); it != Days.end(); ++it)
            {
                cout << it->first << " " << it->second << '\n';
            }
```

E0349 missing operator "<<" corresponding to these operands
C2679 binary "<<": no operator was found that accepts a right operand of type "_Ty2" (or there is no acceptable conversion)
with
[_Ty2 = Day]
how can I do this?

```
void PrintDay(const Day& d, ChangeF Pd)
{
    cout << "Current date:" << d.date << endl << "\n=============================================" << endl << "Number of tasks:" << d.aims;
    cout << "\n=============================================" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < d.aims; i++)
    {
        PrintTask(d.tasks[i], Pd);
    }
}

Day InputDay()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    Day d;
    cout << "\nEnter date dd ENTER mm ENTER yyyy ENTER obe by one" << endl;
    int dd, mm, yyyy;
    dd = DigitInputCheck(1, 30);
    mm = DigitInputCheck(1, 12);
    yyyy = DigitInputCheck(0, 4000);
    ostringstream WriteDate;
    WriteDate << dd << "." << mm << "." << yyyy << endl;
    d.date = WriteDate.str();
    cout << "Number of tasks:" << endl;
    cin >> d.aims;
    for (int i = 0; i < d.aims; i++)
    {
        d.tasks.push_back(InputTask());
    }

    return d;

}
```

Comment: Error message is extremely clear: you didn't overload `operator<<` for type `Day`, so you can't print it

Comment: i would use time as key in map

Comment: Where is the code to "print" a `Day`? This has nothing to do with switching to maps.

Comment: @CruzJean how to do ? sorry ima rly noob in this sphere

Comment: You need to define the function `std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream  &os, const Day &day );`

Comment: @ChrisMM so can you show it in code please.I can upload full code if needed

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to overload the `operator<<` for the type `Day` if you are going to try to use `<<` with it. Since you already have a `PrintDay`, I'll adapt it to work with the operator. I have no idea what `Pd` is supposed to be, so I'm ignoring it. This function should be a *global* function. Since all your fields are public, it doesn't need special access via `friend` either.

```
std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream &os, const Day &day ) {
    os << "Current date:" << d.date << '\n'
        << "\n=============================================\n"
        << "Number of tasks:" << d.aims
        << "\n=============================================\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < d.aims; i++)
    {
        os << d.tasks[i];
    }
}
```

You would also need to add the operator for your `Task` type as well. Given the above, you should be able to make another function for your `PrintTask` function.

Comment: ```ostream& operator<<(ostream& ost, const Task& t)
{
 ChangeF Pt;
 Day d;
 ost << t.study << t.priority;
 string stime = Pt(t.time);
 ost << stime << endl << t.made << endl;
 
}```

Comment: ```ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Day& d)
{
 ChangeF Pd;
 
 os << "Current date:" << d.date << endl
  << "\n=============================================" << endl
  << "Number of tasks:" << d.aims
  << "\n=============================================" << endl;
 for (int i = 0; i < d.aims; i++)
 {
  os << d.date << endl << d.aims;;
 }
}```

Comment: @aigoo038 why are you spamming code in comments? It isnt readable...

Comment: i made it like this,but still dont understand what im doin

Comment: where i need to post it? it is first time using stack

Comment: @aigoo038 if you want to ask for clarification then just ask. If you have a follow up question then you can open a new question

Comment: @aigoo038, the `os` that I use is any `ostream` object, which includes `cout`  So you would just write the function body as if it were any of your Print methods, but just use `os` instead of `cout`  ... If you need more clarification let me know here, or ask a new question.